# Induction on primes, Prime factorial factorisation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I want to prove that it is possible to write any positive integer as a "product" of factorials of prime numbers, however, it can include negative exponents too.
E.g. $22 = (11!)^1 × (7!)^{−1} × (5!)^{−1} × (3!)^{−1} × (2!)^1$. My approach was to prove that all primes can be written in terms of prime factorials, then we could use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

$2=2!$ so it is true for $p=2$. Assume true for all primes less than $k$, where $k$ is prime.

$k = \frac{k!}{(k-1)!}$

$(k-1)!$ can be expressed as a product of primes less than $k$, and by assumption all of these can be expressed as factorials, so it is true for $k$. Therefore true for all primes. Therefore true for all integers.

Does this induction work? I can then immediately say that rationals can also be expressed in this way?

Comment: Looks OK to me (quick read).

Comment: "What is induction?" It means that a specific value $F = 2$ works, and then generalize it to all primes, by proving the fact that if $p_n$ works, then $p_{n+1}$ also works.

Comment: You used the strong induction, perfectly valid argument. For the rationals, you can apply a quotient of products, so a representation also exists for every rational number (for $1$ , you have the empty product)